# Error SQL query: Use SUM method, When #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL, here is my query.
This query working fine but getting multiple rows of amount.

```
SELECT tcc.entry_fees*COUNT(tccc.match_contest_id) as amount 
FROM `tbl_cricket_customer_contests` tccc 
LEFT JOIN tbl_cricket_contest_matches tccm on(tccm.id=tccc.match_contest_id) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_cricket_contests tcc ON (tcc.id=tccm.contest_id) 
WHERE tccc.customer_id = 9 GROUP BY tccc.match_contest_id
```

When use SUM method than getting error
MySQL said:

> #1111 - Invalid use of group function

```
SELECT SUM(tcc.entry_fees*COUNT(tccc.match_contest_id)) as amount 
FROM `tbl_cricket_customer_contests` tccc 
LEFT JOIN tbl_cricket_contest_matches tccm on(tccm.id=tccc.match_contest_id) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_cricket_contests tcc ON (tcc.id=tccm.contest_id) 
WHERE tccc.customer_id = 9 GROUP BY tccc.match_contest_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an aggregate function over another. You need to separate the queries:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) As Amount
FROM 
(
    SELECT tcc.entry_fees*COUNT(tccc.match_contest_id) as amount 
    FROM `tbl_cricket_customer_contests` tccc 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_cricket_contest_matches tccm on(tccm.id=tccc.match_contest_id) 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_cricket_contests tcc ON (tcc.id=tccm.contest_id) 
    WHERE tccc.customer_id = 9 GROUP BY tccc.match_contest_id
) As DT
```

**Update**

As I wrote in the comments, I'm not a MySql expert, but I think this is what you're looking for.
Note I've commented out the `group by` clause in the outer query.

```
SELECT tc.*,
    (
        SELECT SUM(amount) As Amount
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT tcc.entry_fees*COUNT(tccc.match_contest_id) as amount 
            FROM `tbl_cricket_customer_contests` AS tccc 
            LEFT JOIN tbl_cricket_contest_matches AS tccm on(tccm.id=tccc.match_contest_id) 
            LEFT JOIN tbl_cricket_contests AS tcc ON (tcc.id=tccm.contest_id) 
            WHERE tccc.customer_id = tc.id GROUP BY tccc.match_contest_id
        ) As DT
    ) as spendamount
FROM `tbl_customers` As tc
WHERE tc.`is_deleted` = 'N' 
-- Do you really need that group by here? GROUP BY tc.`id` 
ORDER BY tc.`spendamount` DESC
```

Comment: Thank You, Please look again my question. Actually problems is Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: Your question hasn't changed, and my derived table has an alias, so I don't see a problem in my answer...

Comment: Your Answer is helpful but i changed my questions.

Comment: Strange, I've refreshed and didn't see that change in the question before. I'm not a MySql expert but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks improving query But getting same error. I think your some help this screenshot please  see and give update thanks https://i.stack.imgur.com/43J7e.jpg

Comment: I asked New question on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450521/ so please update this

Comment: As I wrote, I'm not a mySql person. I work mainly with SQL Server - where this query should work perfectly. However, since you have started this post with the first two queries, and already have a new post with the last query, I would suggest removing the last query from this post and accepting the answer on the first part, since it's clearly correct.

Comment: Okay, I will removing last question, Please give on this question answer, I know about your profile your  SQL Server  expert but You conceptually right, i thing it's possible your helping. Please look it link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450521

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total amount, don't nest the aggregation functions and remove the `group by`:

```
SELECT SUM(tcc.entry_fees) as amount 
FROM tbl_cricket_customer_contests tccc JOIN
     tbl_cricket_contest_matches tccm
     ON tccm.id = tccc.match_contest_id JOIN
     tbl_cricket_contests tcc
     ON tcc.id = tccm.contest_id
WHERE tccc.customer_id = 9;
```

I also changed the `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`.  You are summing values from the last table, so only matching rows contribute to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```sql
GROUP BY tcc.entry_fees
```

instead of

```sql
GROUP BY tccc.match_contest_id
```

You need to `GROUP BY` with the field that does not contain the aggregation.
`GROUP BY` will group all your `entry_fees` and for each group, count `match_contest_id`

Comment: getting same error when use of GROUP BY tcc.entry_fees

Comment: Can you update your post and show the structure of your tables ?

Comment: Please see this quetion i update with structure of  tables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450521/